# How do you call a function in Powershell with variable argument list

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell function with eight parameters. Two are mandatory and two are mutually exclusive. This gives me 24 permutations of the function call.

It seems that I should be able to craft a string based on the presence of parameter data and then execute that string to call the function, but I haven't hit upon a solution.

This is the XML input, parameters in brackets [] are optional, | means either/or:

```
<TextInsert TargetFile="" StartString="" [IncludeStartString="True"] [EndString="" [IncludeEndString="True"]] [SourceFile=""|InsertText=""] [IgnoreCase="True"] />
```

I had tried constructing a function call by catenating variables to the call as they were discovered, like this:

```
Function MakeInsertTextFunctionCallI  {
param (
    [System.Xml.XmlElement]$Params
)
$IgnoreCase   = $Params.IgnoreCase
$StartString  = $Params.StartString
$IncludeStart = $Params.IncludeStartString
$EndString    = $Params.EndString
$IncludeEnd   = $Params.IncludeEndString
$TargetFile   = $Params.TargetFile
$InsertText   = $Params.InsertText
$SourceFile   = $Params.SourceFile

# Section A #############################################################
$CmdStr = "InsertText -File $TargetFile -StartString $StartString"

If($IncludeStart) {
    $CmdStr += " -IncludeStartString"
}

If($SourceFile) {
    $CmdStr += " -SourceFile $SourceFile"
} else {
    $CmdStr += " -InsertText $InsertText"
}

If($EndString) {
    $CmdStr += " -EndString $EndString"
    If($IncludeEnd) {
        $CmdStr += " -IncludeEndString"
    }
}

If($IgnoreCase) {
    $CmdStr += " -IgnoreCase"
}

#    $CmdStr
#    & $CmdStr
Invoke-Expression $CmdStr
```

But I couldn't get it work. I tried three variations of calling the function. Some of the problems involved embedded quotes in the arguments. Another issue is that I'm using this to edit markup language files so there's a lot of embedded <>" and such symbols. Resulting in this error for the last attempt: Invoke-Expression : The '<' operator is reserved for future use.

The following section of code, however inelegant and unsupportable as it is, does work:

```
# Section B ############################################################
#Possible Parameters
$cTargetFile =   [Convert]::ToInt32("10000000",2) #128
$cStartString =  [Convert]::ToInt32("01000000",2) #64
$cIncludeStart = [Convert]::ToInt32("00100000",2) #32
$cSourceFile =   [Convert]::ToInt32("00010000",2) #16
$cInsertText =   [Convert]::ToInt32("00001000",2) #8
$cEndString =    [Convert]::ToInt32("00000100",2) #4
$cIncludeEnd =   [Convert]::ToInt32("00000010",2) #2
$cIgnoreCase =   [Convert]::ToInt32("00000001",2) #1

$ParamMask = 0
If($IgnoreCase)   { $ParamMask += $cIgnoreCase }
If($StartString)  { $ParamMask += $cStartString }
If($IncludeStart) { $ParamMask += $cIncludeStart }
If($SourceFile)   { $ParamMask += $cSourceFile }
If($InsertText)   { $ParamMask += $cInsertText }
If($EndString)    { $ParamMask += $cEndString }
If($IncludeEnd)   { $ParamMask += $cIncludeEnd }
If($TargetFile)   { $ParamMask += $cTargetFile }

switch($ParamMask) {
    192 { InsertText -File $TargetFile -StartString $StartString -SourceFile $SourceFile }
    193 { InsertText -File $TargetFile -StartString $StartString -SourceFile $SourceFile -IgnoreCase }
    200 { InsertText -File $TargetFile -StartString $StartString -InsertText $InsertText }
    201 { InsertText -File $TargetFile -StartString $StartString -InsertText $InsertText -IgnoreCase }
.
. <some of the 24 permutations removed for brevity>
.
    246 { InsertText -File $TargetFile -StartString $StartString -IncludeStart -EndString $EndString -IncludeEnd -SourceFile $SourceFile }
    247 { InsertText -File $TargetFile -StartString $StartString -IncludeStart -EndString $EndString -IncludeEnd -SourceFile $SourceFile -IgnoreCase }
    238 { InsertText -File $TargetFile -StartString $StartString -IncludeStart -EndString $EndString -IncludeEnd -InsertText $InsertText }
    239 { InsertText -File $TargetFile -StartString $StartString -IncludeStart -EndString $EndString -IncludeEnd -InsertText $InsertText -IgnoreCase }
    Default { #Then log an invalid parameters error}
}
```

I say that Section B is unsupportable because if someone wants to add another parameter to the function, calculating the bit mask and entering all the new permutation in the switch statement will be overly time consuming; as opposed to just adding one more catenation to section A.

Does anyone have any tips for simplifying this code? Or any critique about section A that might improve it's workability?

Comment: Did you try constructing your arguments in a hash table and splatting that to the function?  I'd think that would be much easier than trying to do all of that string concatenation.

Comment: The suggestion by @mjolinor is most likely the way to go. To find more information about splatting, run the command `Get-Help about_Splatting` (or read the same help section online at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx).

Comment: Splatting 'almost' works - it's barfing on sending a value to a [switch] parameter. I've tried "$true",1,$true but in each case it says: Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "Syst
em.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter", parameters of this type only accept booleans or numbers, use $true, $false, 1 or 0 instead.
Still trying to figure this small piece out. Otherwise it looks like a good solution.

Comment: One solution to that is use splatting for all but switch.

Comment: I've never seen $true or $false (no quotes) not work for splatting a switch parameter.

Comment: Splatting works fine for switch parameters. There are samples using switch parameters in the help section; `Get-Help about_Splatting`.

Comment: Huh! I don't what I did wrong the first time but $true without quotes works fine for splatting. Thanks mjolinor. I wish I had an answer I could accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mjolinor provided the answer. Hash splatting works. Here's the final working code.

```
$ParamHash = @{}
If($IgnoreCase)   { $ParamHash.Add("-IgnoreCase",$true) }
If($StartString)  { $ParamHash.Add("-StartString","$StartString") }
If($IncludeStart) { $ParamHash.Add("-IncludeStartString",$true) }
If($SourceFile)   { $ParamHash.Add("-SourceFile","$SourceFile") }
If($InsertText)   { $ParamHash.Add("-InsertText","$InsertText") }
If($EndString)    { $ParamHash.Add("-EndString","$EndString") }
If($IncludeEnd)   { $ParamHash.Add("-IncludeEndString",$true) }
If($TargetFile)   { $ParamHash.Add("-File","$TargetFile") }

InsertText @ParamHash
```

Nice, neat, compact, and readable. Thanks @mjolinor.